# Conforming class to codable protocol in swift4

Tags: swift4, codable

Make conforming struct to Codable (Encodable & Decodable) protocol is super easy: just declare it. But do I have to write all boiler code (CodingEnum, init(from decoder: Decoder), encode(to encoder: Encoder), etc) if I want make class conforming to Codable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you haven't to do it. Example:

```
import Foundation

class Message: Codable {
    let id: Int = 1
    let text: String = "Hello"
}

let message = Message()
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let json = try encoder.encode(message)
print(String(data: json, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
```

Comment: Please read my question again, I’m asking about CLASS, not struct

Comment: classes working as well. example changed to class usage.

Comment: Found why my class can not "auto-conform" to Codable, because it has property of Dictionary [String: Any] (JSON). So how to make Dictionary<String, Any> conform to Codable?

Comment: `[String: Any]` can't conform for `Codable` because `Any` doesn't conform to `Codable` protocol.

Comment: @zzheads https://stackoverflow.com/a/44670454/2778645 here is a link with answer you could help with 'Any' conformance issue.