# How to encode a property with type of JSON dictionary in Swift 4 encodable protocol

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable, decodable

Well, my question is simple. I want to do the same as this answer but for encode:
[How to decode a property with type of JSON dictionary in Swift 4 decodable protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44603248/5124849)

That solution works fine with decode, but I also need encode a `Dictionary<String, Any>`

I can't realize how to write the extension for `KeyedEncodingContainer` and the other extensions, and what methods to write.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by adapting the Decodable code snippet from that question's answer

```
extension KeyedEncodingContainerProtocol where Key == JSONCodingKeys {
    mutating func encodeJSONDictionary(_ value: Dictionary<String, Any>) throws {
        try value.forEach({ (key, value) in
            let key = JSONCodingKeys(key: key)
            switch value {
            case let value as Bool:
                try encode(value, forKey: key)
            case let value as Int:
                try encode(value, forKey: key)
            case let value as String:
                try encode(value, forKey: key)
            case let value as Double:
                try encode(value, forKey: key)
            case let value as Dictionary<String, Any>:
                try encode(value, forKey: key)
            case let value as Array<Any>:
                try encode(value, forKey: key)
            case Optional<Any>.none:
                try encodeNil(forKey: key)
            default:
                throw EncodingError.invalidValue(value, EncodingError.Context(codingPath: codingPath + [key], debugDescription: "Invalid JSON value"))
            }
        })
    }
}

extension KeyedEncodingContainerProtocol {
    mutating func encode(_ value: Dictionary<String, Any>, forKey key: Key) throws {
        var container = self.nestedContainer(keyedBy: JSONCodingKeys.self, forKey: key)
        try container.encodeJSONDictionary(value)
    }

    mutating func encodeIfPresent(_ value: Dictionary<String, Any>?, forKey key: Key) throws {
        if let value = value {
            try encode(value, forKey: key)
        }
    }

    mutating func encode(_ value: Array<Any>, forKey key: Key) throws {
        var container = self.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: key)
        try container.encodeJSONArray(value)
    }

    mutating func encodeIfPresent(_ value: Array<Any>?, forKey key: Key) throws {
        if let value = value {
            try encode(value, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}

extension UnkeyedEncodingContainer {
    mutating func encodeJSONArray(_ value: Array<Any>) throws {
        try value.enumerated().forEach({ (index, value) in
            switch value {
            case let value as Bool:
                try encode(value)
            case let value as Int:
                try encode(value)
            case let value as String:
                try encode(value)
            case let value as Double:
                try encode(value)
            case let value as Dictionary<String, Any>:
                try encode(value)
            case let value as Array<Any>:
                try encode(value)
            case Optional<Any>.none:
                try encodeNil()
            default:
                let keys = JSONCodingKeys(intValue: index).map({ [ $0 ] }) ?? []
                throw EncodingError.invalidValue(value, EncodingError.Context(codingPath: codingPath + keys, debugDescription: "Invalid JSON value"))
            }
        })
    }

    mutating func encodeJSONDictionary(_ value: Dictionary<String, Any>) throws {
        var nestedContainer = self.nestedContainer(keyedBy: JSONCodingKeys.self)
        try nestedContainer.encodeJSONDictionary(value)
    }
}
```

Here's a code snippet for that

However, this code snippet will fail in Swift 4.1 which should be released within the first half of 2018.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will give it a try!

Comment: @MauroTaroco I hope that my answer was not too late :P

Comment: hehe well, it was a little. But no problem with that, never it's too late, I will try in my next project! thanks!!!

Comment: @MauroTaroco I've fixed swift 4.1, but it's not 100% tested https://github.com/3D4Medical/gltf_scenekit/blob/master/Sources/gltf_scenekit/GLTF/JSONCodingKeys.swift

Comment: @SAKrisT awesome!! also will give a try in the next project! Thanks for share it!

Comment: @MauroTaroco That url is private. Could you post a code snippet for 4.1?

Comment: @Jeremiah the url was shared by SAKrisT, not me :D

Comment: Whoops. @SAKrisT Can you post a code snippet for 4.1?

Comment: @Jeremiah https://github.com/3D4Medical/glTFSceneKit/blob/master/Sources/glTFSceneKit/GLTF/JSONCodingKeys.swift