# Fatal error: Dictionary<String, Any> does not conform to Decodable because Any does not conform to Decodable

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4, decodable

I'm trying to use swift 4 to parse a local json file:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "lastId": null,
    "hasMore": false,
    "foundEndpoint": "https://endpoint",
    "error": null
}
```

This is the function I'm using:

```
    func loadLocalJSON() {

        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "localJSON", ofType: "json") {
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

            do {
                let data  = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let colors = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: Any].self, from: data)
                print(colors)
            }
            catch { print("Local JSON not loaded")}
        }
    }
}
```

but I keep getting the error:

> Fatal error: Dictionary does not conform to Decodable
>   because Any does not conform to Decodable.

I tried using the "AnyDecodable" approach on this stackoverflow page: [How to decode a property with type of JSON dictionary in Swift 4 decodable protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603248/how-to-decode-a-property-with-type-of-json-dictionary-in-swift-4-decodable-proto)

but it jumps to the 'catch' statement:   `catch { print("Local JSON not loaded")` when being used. Does anyone know how to parse this JSON data in Swift 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you are misunderstanding how `Codable` works. It's based on concrete types. `Any` is not supported.

In your case you might create a struct like

```
struct Something: Decodable {
    let success : Bool
    let lastId : Int?
    let hasMore: Bool
    let foundEndpoint: URL
    let error: String?
}
```

And decode the JSON

```
func loadLocalJSON() {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "localJSON", withExtension: "json")!
    let data  = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    let colors = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Something.self, from: data)
    print(colors)
}
```

Any crash will reveal a design error. The sense of using `null` in a file in the main bundle is another question.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense, its works when setup like that. Thanks!

Comment: Note that you can use a single `try` for both `let colors = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Something.self, from: Data(contentsOf: url))`

Comment: In most cases we just need a general solution, give me a dictionary or other types contain only built-in types, we don't want to create a class which conforms Decodable for every json files. Maybe JSONSerialization is the right way.

Answer (score 4):

I used [quicktype](https://app.quicktype.io?gist=02c8b82add3ced7bb419f01d3a94019f&l=swift) to generate Codables and marshaling code:

https://app.quicktype.io?gist=02c8b82add3ced7bb419f01d3a94019f&l=swift

I gave it an array of samples based on your sample data:

```
[
  {
    "success": true,
    "lastId": null,
    "hasMore": false,
    "foundEndpoint": "https://endpoint",
    "error": null
  },
  {
    "success": true,
    "lastId": 123,
    "hasMore": false,
    "foundEndpoint": "https://endpoint",
    "error": "some error"
  }
]
```

This tells quicktype to assume that the `null` values in your first sample are sometimes `Int` and `String` – you can change these if they aren't the possible types. The resulting Codable generated is:

```
struct Local: Codable {
    let success: Bool
    let lastID: Int?
    let hasMore: Bool
    let foundEndpoint: String
    let error: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case success
        case lastID = "lastId"
        case hasMore, foundEndpoint, error
    }
}
```