# Swift - Encode and Decode a dictionary [String:Any] into plist

Tags: swift, dictionary, encoding, nested, decode

I am trying to store the dictionary in my class Marker but it is throwing an error saying it is not encodable or decodable. I can see the error is caused by the [String: Any] but how can I go around it?

```
var buttonActions : [String: [String: [String:Any]]] = [:]
```

Save and Load

```
func saveData() {
    let dataFilePath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName).plist")

    let encoder = PropertyListEncoder()
    do {
        let data = try encoder.encode(markerArray)
        try data.write(to: dataFilePath!)
        print("Saved")
    } catch {
        print("Error Encoding \(error)")
    }
}

func loadData() {
    let dataFilePath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName).plist")

    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: dataFilePath!){
        let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
        do {
            markerArray = try decoder.decode([Marker].self, from: data)
        } catch {
            print("Decode Error \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Class

```
class Marker : Encodable, Decodable {
    var UUIDpic: UUID = UUID()
    var alpha: Int = 1
    var buttonType: Int = 0
    var buttonActions : [String: [String: [String:Any]]] = [:]
    var buttonNameColor: String = ""
    var buttonNameFontSize: Int = 10
    var buttonShape: String = ""
    var loggerRect: String = ""
    var maskColor: String = ""
    var name: String = ""
}
```

Comment: You can't encode/decode `Any`. What types of values are actually in that inner dictionary?

Comment: Inner dictionary contains a string and an array of strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally worked it out with the help of Andrada.

I added a second struct which held the action and by passed having to use [string:any]

```
class Marker : Encodable, Decodable {
var UUIDpic: UUID = UUID()
var alpha: Int = 1
var buttonType: Int = 0
var buttonAction : [String: [ButtonAction]] = [:] //Dictionary I edited using the new struct
var buttonNameColor: String = ""
var buttonNameFontSize: Int = 10
var buttonShape: String = ""
var loggerRect: String = ""
var maskColor: String = ""
var name: String = ""
}
```

Below is the struct I added

```
struct ButtonAction: Codable {
var action: String
var array_linked_of_buttons: [[String:String]]

init(action: String, array_linked_of_buttons: [[String:String]]) {
 self.action = action
 self.array_linked_of_buttons = array_linked_of_buttons
    }
}
```

Make sure to init your struct or it won't work.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately you cannot use `encode` or `decode` on generic types containing `Any` (e.g. `[String: Any]` or `[Any]`). `Any` does not conform to protocols `Encodable` nor `Decodable` and Swift doesn't know how to encode/decode it. You must use a concrete generic type for your dictionary (e.g. `[String: String]`).

If you still need to use a general type like `Any` you have to implement `encode(to:)` and `init(from:)` methods. Another option would be to use a `struct` instead of your `[String: [String: [String:Any]]]` which conforms to `Codable` (`Encodable & Decodable`). You will still have to implement `encode(to:)` and `init(from:)` methods in that struct, but the bright side is that you will not have to write the `encoder.encode()` story for all the properties like you would have to if you implement them in the `Marker` class.

Comment: Hi Andrada, any chance you could provide a link or an example? I changed my class to a struct and I kind of understand  what you mean but I can't work out to implement it sorry.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603248/how-to-decode-a-property-with-type-of-json-dictionary-in-swift-4-decodable-proto?fbclid=IwAR2jstxmdG4bbdIJBKRZJXzXLi5Uyk95RI3he1yWw26fKy1ZQNSha1HsJcs also, you don't need to change your class into a struct, you rather need an additional struct for that dictionary

Comment: Thanks Andrada, I'll try to implement it now

Comment: I went throught the link but I didn't understand how to implement the most popular answer so I used the github linked to it that answer. https://gist.github.com/mbuchetics/5d5600c50c369bea29db4a3986cee94f This kind of work but not if I want to add an array in [String:Any]. Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Thanks Andrada  for the help. I managed to work it out because of you :)