# Swift Codable: Cannot decode dictionary of type [String: Any] or [String: Decodable]

Tags: ios, swift, codable

In my custom initializer I'd like to decode a dictionary from JSON and then assign its values to properties in the class. To my surprise, compiler does not allow me to decode the dictionary, I get the error:

```
Value of protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to 'Decodable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
```

If I try to decode dictionary of type [String: Decodable] the error message says:

```
Value of protocol type 'Decodable' cannot conform to 'Decodable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
```

My initializer looks like this:

```
public let total: Int

required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    ...
    if let dict = try container.decodeIfPresent([String: Any].self, forKey: .tracks),
           let value = dict["total"] as? Int { // Error is displayed at this line
        total = value
    } else {
        total = 0
    }
    ...
}
```

When I looked for the answer I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46049763/7235585) and according to it the code above should not cause any problems.

Comment: "I'd like to decode a dictionary from JSON and then assign its values to properties in the class" Are you in fact looking for `nestedContainer`?

Comment: "I'd like to decode a dictionary from JSON and then assign its values to properties in the class" Are you in fact looking for `nestedContainer`? Also "according to it the code above should not cause any problems." did you add the extension as the user did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `nestedContainer`. It helps you "skip" a hierarchy level in your JSON. Ie: let's imagine that in your code, it's all in the same level (one struct), but in the JSON, it's not, there is a sub dictionary.

For test purpose, your JSON might look like:

```
{
    "title": "normal",
    "tracks": {
                   "name": "myName",
                   "total": 3
              }
}
```

If we want in our model:

```
struct TestStruct: Codable {
    let title: String
    let name: String
    let total: Int
}
```

We need to use `nestedContainer(keyedBy: forKey:)`:

```
extension TestStruct {
    enum TopLevelKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case title
        case tracks
    }
    
    enum NestedLevelCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case total
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: TopLevelKeys.self)
        self.title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        let subcontainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: NestedLevelCodingKeys.self, forKey: TopLevelKeys.tracks)
        self.name = try subcontainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.total = try subcontainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .total) //You can use here a `decodeIfPresent()` if needed, use default values, etc.

    }
}
```

In your sample, you used `decodeIfPresent()` for the subdictionary. It's unclear if it was for test purpose, or if the sub dictionary was sometimes not present.
If that's the case and you can have a JSON like this:

```
{
    "title": "normal"
}
```

Then, before calling `nestedContainer(keyedBy: forKey:)`, use `if container.contains(TopLevelKeys.tracks) {}` and set default values if needed in the `else` case.